# Trying to compute Pisano Period For Fibonacci no modulo m where m is a number

Tags: java

**CODE -:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Big 
{
    public static long m;
    public static int ind;
    public static long first_no,second_no;
    public static boolean flag = false;
    public static long fib_no;

    public static int find_index(long mod_no)
    {
        int i = 1;
        first_no= 0;
        second_no= 1;

        while(flag != true)
        {
            fib_no = first_no + second_no;
            second_no = first_no;
            first_no = fib_no;

            if( fib_no%mod_no == 0)
            {
                if(((first_no%mod_no + second_no%mod_no)%mod_no) == 1)
                {
                    ind  = i;
                    flag = true;
                    System.out.println("i : " + i);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }    
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        } 

        return ind;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i=0;
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Mod No : ");
        m = num.nextLong();

        ind = find_index(m);
        System.out.println(ind);
    }
}
```

Here i have taken the m as an input where m is the number by which the modulus will be taken. I take m as the input and get the period as the output.

I am getting correct answers for some and wrong answers for some. Awaiting some help on this code to compute the period

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve and give test results

Comment: @JFMeier see this link -: http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/fibonacci/fiblist.htm   
On this link on entering the mod i will get the corresponding period. For example if i give input 10. I will get output as 60.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of the Fibonacci series is wrong. You are trying to build up a three consecutive Fibonnacci numbers, but setting

```
second_no = first_no;
```

is wrong. You should probably print out the Fibonacci series you generate to understand if it is correct. Furthermore, the construction of your while loop is overly complex (either use the flag or use a break, if you aim for a break, use a for loop instead to manage the counter).

Comment: i saw by printing the fibonacci series and i am getting some numbers as negative. Can you provide some method so that these numbers are in range. I added one system.out.println(fib_no) statement before the if statement. Can you help me in fixing this issue by printing correct numbers.

Comment: You can iterate through the fibonacci sequence by having two variables f1, f2 with start values 0,1, a auxiliary variable fnew and an iteration step fNew = f1+ f2; f1 = f2; f2 = fNew.

Comment: Its not working still... Displaying the negative values

Comment: I think by reading about Fibonacci numbers, you should be able to construct a correct Fibonacci sequence yourself. If you run into fundamental problems, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare variable as long to avoid negative answer, it occurs due to overflow of integer.

Comment: You could precise which variable shall be declared.